# send HTTP/1.1 302 Found header when file not found

Tags: php, header

I want my server to send that header when a non-existent file or directory is requested.
E.g if this is requested `http://example.com/qkwnen` instead of sending a 404 header i want it to send a 302 one. How can this be made possible? It'd have to do with what to place into my .htaccess file.
This is to also stop directory/file brute forcing tools.
Thanks, i really do not understand why someone thumbed this down.
It can be done by adding the following line to the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 302 /test.html
```

But the problem is it doesn't redirect to `http://example.com/test.html`.

Comment: The server i use is apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /send302.php
```

Then, in send302.php you can do something like

```
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
```

Comment: @BobSm So give me five! :)